# How can I pass HTML data from Python to an already created HTML page for display?

Tags: python, html, django, jinja2

I am working on a Django project and would like to take markdown texts, convert them to HTML, and then display them on the browser. I did some research and tried different ways, but none worked as I wanted.

This is my code:

Python:

```
class HTMLFilter(HTMLParser):
    text = ""
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.text += data

def display_entry(request, entry):

    if util.get_entry(entry.capitalize()) != None:

        markdowner = Markdown()
        data = markdowner.convert(util.get_entry(entry.capitalize()))

        html = HTMLFilter()
        html.feed(data)
        
        body = html.text

        return render(request, "encyclopedia/display.html", {
            "title": entry,
            "body": body
        })

    else:

       return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "entry": entry.capitalize()
       })
```

This is how the function (get_entry()) from the util module looks like:

```
def get_entry(title):
    try:
        f = default_storage.open(f"entries/{title}.md")
        return f.read().decode("utf-8")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
```

I use the [python-markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) package to convert markdown language to HTML and it works perfectly. Below is an example of the text that was converted into HTML.

```
<h1>Django</h1> <p>Django is a web framework written using <a href="/wiki/Python">Python</a> that allows for the design of web applications that generate <a href="/wiki/HTML">HTML</a> dynamically.</p>
```

My biggest challenge is displaying this text as normal HTML to the browser. This is what my HTML file looks like:

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ body }}

{% endblock %}
```

After using HTMLParser from html.parser I get these results:

```
Django Django is a web framework written using Python that allows for the design of web applications that generate HTML dynamically.
```

This is not what I want as it completely ignores headings, links, and other important HTML tags.

I did try others ways but did not work as I expected.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for a HTML parser, as ou already get HTML from the markdown library.

```py
def display_entry(request, entry):
    entry_content = util.get_entry(entry.capitalize())
    if entry_content != None:
        markdowner = Markdown()
        body_html = markdowner.convert(entry_content)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/display.html", {
            "title": entry,
            "body": body_html
        })
    else:
       return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "entry": entry.capitalize()
       })
```

In your template you have to use the `safe` filter to prevent django from escaping your string.

Django Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-safe

```html
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ body|safe }}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your template like this to render HTML strings using `safe` filter

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %} {{ title }} {% endblock %}

{% block body %}

    {{ body |safe }}

{% endblock %
```

for more info https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatefilter-safe